# Git added file is not tracked

Tags: git

[image]

When I change the content of the added file, git detects it's modified but says "Changes not staged for commit" as the image. I have to add the file again to commit every time. This isn't right. What's happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you `git push` it ?

Comment: *When I change the content of the added file, git detects it's modified but says "Changes not staged for commit" as the image. I have to add the file again to commit every time. This isn't right.* [That's completely normal behavior](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Staging-Modified-Files).

Comment: seems like you are wrong. please read this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Staging-Modified-Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the whole point with git. Once you change a file it tracks it as changed, in order to **"track"** changes you have to add it to the staging area = Preparing it for the commit.

Read this for more information:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes

If you want to add all your files at once you can always do : `git add -A`. It will add and remove all your modified/ deleted files

Comment: Hmm. I am coming from mercurial. I guess git is quite different.